# Using estimates for chi-square test for sample size estimation for logrank test

Tags: chi-squared-test, sample-size, logrank-test

Is it possible to use estimates for chi-square test to estimate sample size for logrank test? I remember that I have seen papers that do it that way.

The problem is that, when you have to estimate sample size for time-to-event outcomes, you usually do not know the distributions of the times in the comparison groups. So the estimates that substitute one or another time distribution may be more wrong than simple estimates employing just chi-square test.